# pm2 start runs but website is not working correctly

Tags: node.js, pm2, yarnpkg

I have a nodeJS project built with yarn. I can run the application on the server using 'yarn start'. It is working correctly. It runs the dist/app.js file when running with yarn. But when i run it using pm2 start app.js, pm2 process starts but application does not works. Any idea?

Comment: run `pm2 logs <yourappname>`. What do the logs say?

Comment: it shows that failed to start script gulp serve. In my application package.json start script is gulp serve.

Comment: Try to run the app with `pm2 start npm --name myapp -- start`.
This tells pm2 to run `npm start` under the name `myapp`.

Comment: i tried with it but getting the same error.

Comment: Sorry now it's working it was just browser issue.