# Node app shows 'service downtime or low capacity'

Tags: node.js, pm2

I am running node with vps 1gb ram. It works well with nodemon but when i tried

```
node app.js &
```

And

```
forever start app.js
```

And

```
pm2 start app.js
```

It showed service downtime or low capacity... i rebooted by vps to free up the ram uet same issue how do i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question in this thread

[pm2 start runs but website is not working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49470269/pm2-start-runs-but-website-is-not-working-correctly)

So in case you faced the same challenge... that is my solution